# Можно ли повлиять на контент из меню?

Tags: android, java

Вообщем, есть главное активити (на ней и должны будут происходить изменение) и есть  Drawer menu тоже в этой активити, как раз с ExpandableListView и checkbox для каждой группы и child. Мне нужно что бы получилось, что  при нажатии checkbox для одного или нескольких элементов какое либо действие отображалось в главной активити или изменяло его

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ExpandableListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private MyExpandableAdapter mAdapter;

    private List<String> mListForGroup;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> mMapForChild;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList =(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.myexpandablelistview);

        initData();
        mAdapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(this, mListForGroup, mMapForChild);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnChildClickListener(myOnChildClickListener);
        mDrawerList.setOnGroupClickListener(myOnGroupClickListener);
        mDrawerList.setOnGroupCollapseListener(myOnGroupCollapseListener);
        mDrawerList.setOnGroupExpandListener(myOnGroupExpandListener);

            // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

    }
    private void initData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mListForGroup = new ArrayList<String>();
        mMapForChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        mListForGroup.add("Цвета");
        mListForGroup.add("Картинки");

        List<String> listGroupA = new ArrayList<String>();
        listGroupA.add("1");
        listGroupA.add("2");
        listGroupA.add("3");

        List<String> listGroupB = new ArrayList<String>();
        listGroupB.add("1");
        listGroupB.add("2");
        listGroupB.add("3");

        mMapForChild.put(mListForGroup.get(0), listGroupA);
        mMapForChild.put(mListForGroup.get(1), listGroupB);

    }
    OnChildClickListener myOnChildClickListener = new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            return true;
        }

        };

    OnGroupClickListener myOnGroupClickListener = new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {

            return false;
        }
    };

    OnGroupCollapseListener myOnGroupCollapseListener = new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            // group collapse at groupPosition
        }
    };

    OnGroupExpandListener myOnGroupExpandListener = new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            // group expand at groupPosition
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    }

АДАПТЕР

    public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = "myLogs";
    private Context context;
    private List<String> listGroup;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> listChild;

    public MyExpandableAdapter(Context c, List<String> lg,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> lc) {
        context = c;
        listGroup = lg;
        listChild = lc;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return listChild.get(listGroup.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.exp_list_child_item,
                    null);
        }

        TextView textViewItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);

        String text = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        textViewItem.setText(text);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return listChild.get(listGroup.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return listGroup.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return listGroup.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.exp_list_group_item,
                    null);
        }

        String textGroup = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

        // get application resource/drawable not in Activity class, using
        // context

        final CheckBox chek = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        chek.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d(TAG, "cheked  " + isChecked + groupPosition);
                chekedgrop(isChecked, groupPosition);
            }

            private void chekedgrop(boolean isChecked, int groupPosition) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Activity activity = null;
                switch (groupPosition) {
                case 0:
                    if (chek.isChecked()) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "adapter  " + isChecked + groupPosition);

                    } else {

                    }

                    break;
                case 1:

                    Log.d(TAG, "adapter  f " + isChecked + groupPosition);
                    break;
                case 2:

                    Log.d(TAG, "adapter  n " + isChecked + groupPosition);
                    break;
                case 3:

                    Log.d(TAG, "adapter l  " + isChecked + groupPosition);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
            }

        });
        TextView textViewGroup = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.group);
        textViewGroup.setText(textGroup);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Так в чём проблема? Вешаете listener на каждый нужный checkbox в виде this ссылки на текущее Activity. То есть Activity должно implements ..listener (например, OnCheckedChangedListener). И конкретно в этих методах обрабатываете изменения состояния checkbox'ов и изменения в Activity.